# Question marks instead of Russian letters in the database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, character-encoding

Signs of the question instead of Russian letters and does not write Russian letters in the database.

Here is an example code that makes a selection of a news list from a database:

```
  public static function getList( $numRows=1000000, $order="publicationDate DESC" ) {
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate FROM articles
            ORDER BY " . $conn->quote($order) . " LIMIT :numRows ";

    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->execute();
    $list = array();

    while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
      $article = new Article( $row );
      $list[] = $article;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalRows";
    $totalRows = $conn->query( $sql )->fetch();
    $conn = null;
    return ( array ( "results" => $list, "totalRows" => $totalRows[0] ) );
  }
```

`$conn->query( "SET CHARSET utf8" );` - Does not help
`mysql:charset=utf8;` - don`t work
Database structure:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2815.png)

Comment: change character Collation of mysql table to `utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: @urfusion It is the default but does not help

Comment: `?????` usually means that the data was not stored correctly.  See "question marks" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored for specifics about the cause.